# MySQL. I want to get a percentage of emails, which were clicked not later than 10 min after user received an email

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have 2 tables in MySQL:

```
emails_sent(
id int primary key,
id_type int,
date_sent datetime)

emails_clicks(
id int primary key,
id_email int,
date_click datetime,
foreign key(id_email) references emails_sent(id))
```

I want to write a query, that will return a percentage of emails, that were clicked not later than 10 min after user received an email. Grouped by each type of email (id_type). How can i do this?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hey ArbiterNick, welcome to the site! I'd suggest taking a peek at the posting guidelines in order to get a better sense of what works well here on Stackoverflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I would suggest avoiding using phrases like "I want to" in titles and try to focus on the problem at hand.  For example, "Query to compare dates and select rows with a 10 minute threshold" reads better and is more concise for what you're looking for. I'd also suggest to post any attempts you may have tried, it helps people better gauge what is and isn't working for you.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a conditional average.

In MySQL, that would be:

```
select s.id_type, avg(c.date_click < s.date_sent + interval 10 minute) res
from email_sent s
left join email_clicks c on c.id_email = s.id
group by id_type
```

For each each row in `email_sent`, the query recovers the corresponding row in `email_clicks`; if the email was clicked less than 10 minutes, the condition within `avg()` returns `1`, else `0`. The average gives you the ratio of emails that were clicked less than 10 minutes after being sent (as a decimal value between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0):

Note:  This assumes SQL Server (one of the original tags).

You can use a subquery to get the first click and then aggregate:

```
select s.id_type,
       avg(case when first_click_date < dateadd(minute, 10, date_sent)
                then 1.0 else 0
           end) as num_clicks
from (select s.*,
             (select min(date_click) 
              from email_clicks c
              where c.id_email = s.id
             ) as first_click_date
      from email_sent s
     ) s
group by id_type;
```

This handles users that click multiple times, 10 minutes later or not.